# Class constant as array key

Tags: php, arrays, key, constants

Please take a look at following code:

```
...
class LanguageResources {
    const SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY = 'lang';

    public static function getLanguageSettingsFilePath() {

        if (isset($_GET[LanguageResources::SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY])) {
....
```

I obtain an PHP error message for the very last line. What's wrong with array index access via constant value?

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY - assumed 'SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY' in ...languages.php on line 17
```

Comment: use `self::SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY` Also read the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php It will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: You didn't close the `{` after languageResources

Comment: no, he just decided not to show the rest of the code...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside the class that the constant was defined in, you must reference it as `self::SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY` instead.

Comment: Sometimes my stomach drops when I discover something new about php even after years of programming...especially when it's this simple...will it ever end? :} Thanks @Tularis

Answer (score 2):

You should use this :

```
self::SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY
```

instead  of this:

```
LanguageResources::SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY
```

Prooflink:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my IDE had no write access to the htdocs folder and didn't copy the latest source to the destination directory (w/o warning).

It works with `$_GET[LanguageResources::SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY]`as well as with `$_GET[self::SESSION_LANGUAGE_KEY]`.

I received much more "notice" alerts which represent some kind of "warnings". In order to disable them you have to edit your `php.ini` and add `~E_NOTICE`:

```
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```